# Total confusion about Ubuntu!

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, windows-7

Ok, here's the story.

I installed Ubuntu a couple of days ago (alongside Windows 7), I have a 128 gb SSD, a 1TB HDD and a 500GB External HDD. I accidentally installed Ubuntu onto the External HDD. I didn't feel like this should matter, I had plenty of space and the files on my externall HDD weren't **extremely important**. The installation went fine, the next time I booted it came up with a 'no such device' error which I fixed by re-installing GRUB via an Ubuntu CD.

**THE PROBLEM IS** everytime I boot my pc, I must go into my boot menu (ASRock motherboard) and select to boot from my External HDD, GRUB then pops up and gives me the option of booting WIndows or Ubuntu. If I don't go into the boot menu, my PC displays nothing on the screen. I can't set my boot priority to the External HDD (for whatever reason) so I am struggling to see a fix for this.

**MY QUESTION IS!** How can I set my PC to boot either:

1. GRUB (Boot from the external HDD)
   or
2. Windows 7 (being my preferred operating system [at the moment], so I then I have the option to manually do what I'm currently doing to boot Ubuntu when I want to use it)

P.S I will happily give you any information you want so long as you guide me a little!

Thanks in advance,

Fletcher.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disconnect the external hard drive, then see if it boots. My guess is that at its worst you would have to rewrite the master boot record or something, for wandows but i don't know if your windows is on the solid state drive or the terabyte drive, anyways there are a number of ways to approach this you can drop in the old windows 7 disk and fire up a dos command prompt and type fixboot, or fixmbr you could us a generic freedos, and do the same i have not worked much with solid state drives so much so i cant tell you from experience but i think if you know how to run the command prompt you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Fletcher,

I'm not so sure, but if I've correctly understood you have a situation more or less similar to this scenario:

128 Gb SSD, say /dev/sda, with Windows 7

1 Tb HDD, say /dev/sdb, for data

500 Mb external HDD, say /dev/sdc, originally for data, now with ubuntu AND grub

and you want to boot both from windows or ubuntu without being obligated to choose the exterrnal HDD from BIOS.

In this case, what about reinstalling grub on /dev/sda? I don't think it's impossible.

Cheers,
Silvia